# Make multiple counters count up using different data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, counter

I am trying to make multiple counters count up forever (from when you land on site) but I want them to count up in different increments depending on the amount set in the "data-speed" attribute. For example, one counts up 100,200,300 and the other counts up 300,400,500. I want to be able to add multiple different containers with different data speeds without adding any more JavaScript.

I have this in my head:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  timer = setInterval("countUP()", 1000);
});

var counter = 0;
var timer;

function countUP() {
  speed = parseInt($(".countup").attr("data-speed"));
  counter = counter + speed;
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = counter.toLocaleString("en");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div id="money" class="countup" data-speed="100">0</div>
  <div class="text">Let's count up</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div id="money" class="countup" data-speed="300">0</div>
  <div class="text">Let's count up differently</div>
```

Comment: looks like it works? https://jsfiddle.net/qynouLf5/ Are you sure you've included jQuery? Any errors in console? Also, you don't need to repeat the same ID for 2 divs; just use the class to select them and loop through them

Comment: Thanks but I want both counters to count up by different amounts - at the moment it is just one counter counting up! Oh yes will remove repeat id!

Comment: I want lets count up differently to count up by 300 each time!

Comment: then the problem is that you're selecting the div *by ID*, but getElementById only selects the first ID it comes across. Instead use `getElementsByClassName`, loop through the array that it returns and set `speed` within that loop so its different for each div

Comment: you could try something like https://jsfiddle.net/qynouLf5/1/? there's probably better ways but it works

Comment: This works perfectly!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id, same class to reference difference elements with different attributes, hence Javascript is stuck at the first element. What I have done is set the target div with a class `counted` and run a foreach loop that finds a child element span.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  timer = setInterval("countUP()", 1000);
});

var counter = 0;

function countUP() {
  var elem = $(".counted");
  elem.each(function() {
    var speed = 0;

    var span = $(this).children('span');
    var count = parseInt(span.text());
    speed = parseInt(span.attr("data-speed"));
    counter = count + speed;
    var counted = counter;
    span.text(counted);


  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container counted">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span id="money" class="countup" data-speed="100">0</span>
  <div class="text">Let's count up</div>
</div>

<div class="container counted">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span id="money" class="countup" data-speed="300">0</span>
  <div class="text">Let's count up differently</div>
```

Comment: How do I add another counter? Creating another container breaks it?

Comment: Actually I have just noticed that the first counter doesn't go up by 100! They both go up by bigger increments!

Comment: It's fixed ... It was just a matter of resetting the speed to zero and getting the value from the div in every loop