# How to apply the same function to all button?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add the same function to all plus button so that each time I click on any of these plus buttons, the number will increase by 1 ,in this case, 12 will become 13 then 14 etc.

```js
const countUp = document.querySelector('.countUp')
const countDown = document.querySelector('.countDown')
const counter = document.querySelector('.num')
let count = counter.textContent

function countUp() {
  countUp.forEach((count) => {
    count.addEventlistener('click', () => {
      count++
      counter.innerText = count
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">
  <button class="countUp">+</button>
  <span class="num">12</span>
  <button class="countDown">-</button>
</div>

<div class="rating">
  <button class="countUp">+</button>
  <span class="num">12</span>
  <button class="countDown">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The linked duplicate addresses the primary question about putting event listeners on multiple elements. A secondary issue is the distinction between counters for each button group. You'd need to manage that with a more elaborate data structure. One question per post, though. :) [ask]

Comment: Unfortunately the question has now been closed, but here's a working version which unifies the event handlers, and also combines the actions of both buttons by using a `data` attribute to contain the action: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/u78cjfr0/

Comment: Here's another example on an existing question. It uses jQuery, but the principle is the same.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629316/make-multiple-counters-count-up-using-different-data-attributes

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about is iterating through all the `rating` divs and then within the `rating` divs I would add listeners to each of the buttons. The method `.querySelectorAll` helps you to fetch all the elements that are identified by a selector where are `.querySelector` only gives you the first one.

Furthermore, the query selector methods are present on the each DOM element which then only perform the query on children of that element.

Below is one way of doing the iterations and assigning the listeners for your current HTML structure.

```js
const ratingElements = document.querySelectorAll('div.rating')

ratingElements.forEach(ratingElement => {
    const countUpButton = ratingElement.querySelector('button.countUp')
    const countDownButton = ratingElement.querySelector('button.countDown')
    const counterDisplayElement = ratingElement.querySelector('count')

    countUpButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const currentCount = Number(counterDisplayElement.innerHTML);
        counterDisplayElement.innerHTML = String(currentCount + 1);
    })

    countDownButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const currentCount = Number(counterDisplayElement.innerHTML);
        counterDisplayElement.innerHTML = String(currentCount - 1);
    })
})
```

Comment: That won't be sufficient since the function doesn't currently distinguish between countUp/countDown elements.

Comment: It is sufficient as you can choose what function to assign to which collection of elements. All the countUp elements can be given the add count listener and similarly the countDown elements can be given a subtract count listener

Comment: They can, but you haven't explained how to design code that achieves the goal by doing that.

Comment: @Quentin Hopefully now, the code snippet helps make it more clear what needs to be done. Thanks!

Comment: You have a *single* pair of `count` and `counter` variables that are shared between all the buttons … which was my original criticism.

Comment: @Quentin Apologies, I completely misunderstood what you were trying to say. I have pushed an edit now, hope that is more acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll to get each element and then use forEach to add the function to the onclick event.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.countUp').forEach(element=>{
    element.onclick = function(){count++}
})
```

Comment: The question implies that each event listener should modify a different pair of countUp/countDown elements. You remove the code that modifies the elements entirely.

Comment: @Quentin, I'm not saying that what I wrote should replace their code, but It should be used in addition to some of what is already there.

Comment: @Quentin I believe the intent of this answer is to depict the usage of the querySelectorAll method and show an example usage instead of give an exact excerpt that would work word for word

Comment: @BurhanuddinSalim — I can see what the intention of the answer is. I think that the intention of the answer does not sufficiently solve the problem expressed in the question to be a good answer.

Comment: @Quentin Fair enough.